# Tensorflow js : How to Convert Frozen model to a web-friendly format?

Tags: tensorflow

I have a file called `frozen_inference_graph.pb`, and I want to do the same things in [this document](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-converter#step-1-converting-a-savedmodel-to-a-web-friendly-format). I try to type the commands in cmd or change the input_path in `converter.py`, but it does't work. The error message just states `input_path must be set`.

Could anyone tell me how to type the commands in detail or where to modify the arguments in the document mentioned above? I have browsed some questions  related to convert model, though I saw there are some similar questions, I still not understand how to make it works.

[image: Screenshot of file]

Comment: Corrected formatting and language.

Comment: Thanks for your input.

Comment: Did you able to convert the file to web-friendly format??